# Serializing JSON To Spring RequestBody with int array

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I have a Spring controller method that specifies a `@RequestBody` as a parameter. The class for the request body looks something like this

```
public class myClass {
     CustomObject obj
     int x
     int y
     int[] values
     Character c

     //getters and setters
}
```

I'm writing unit tests and am having trouble setting the `int[] values` element through a normal JSONobject. I would prefer not to use a JSONArray if possible, as the other elements are passed through just fine through a JSONObject as follows:

```
JSONObject requestParams = new JSONObject();

if(obj != null)
     requestParams.put("obj", obj);

if(c != null)
     requestParams.put("c", c);
```

I've tried `requestParams.put("values", Arrays.toString(values))` where values is defined as `int[] values = new int[]{10,20,30,40,50,60,10,15,20,30,40,55}` but am still getting a 400 error when I try to send the request, only when `values` is not null.

How do I send this list of values to the RequestBody class through a JSONObject?

Comment: it should work normally. Can you post your controller method and sample data how you sending to controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use like below:

```
//prepare list 
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(10);
list.add(20);
...
list.add(100);

JSONArray array = new JSONArray();

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
array.put(list.get(i));
}
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

try {
obj.put("values", array);
}catch(JSONException ee){

 }
```

above is simlified way you can reduce boiler plate code.

Answer (score 1):

you can't parse array to object,try to parse to `ArrayNode` using `ObjectMapper`:

`int[] values = new int[]{10,20,30,40,50,60,10,15,20,30,40,55};
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        ArrayNode node = mapper.valueToTree(values);`